# My site isn't ranking of Alexa

Tags: ranking, alexa

My site is online for more than 3 months now but I don't have Alexa rank. I don't understand why.

Could anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Alexa ranking is not at all important. So don't give too much attention to Alexa ranking.

Comment: Alexa rank is generated if users (who visit your site) have the Alexa toolbar installed in their browser.

Comment: While this question is rather basic, many webmasters may want to know why their site doesn't have an Alexa rank.   A good answer explaining when Alexa updates their rankings and why Alexa rank doesn't matter would be much more helpful than down votes on the question.

Comment: I also don't believe that zigojacko's suggested duplicate is appropriate because it doesn't cover how quickly new sites typically get a ranking.

Comment: Alexa can take some time to discover a site. In fact it is exactly at the rate it takes an Alexa toolbar user to discover the site. Ranking can change from every few days to months. It all depends upon the traffic. I answered 2 SE Alexa questions that inspired me to write a more complete answer here: http://www.closetnoc.org/?i=definitive-proof-that-alexa-sucks It explains exactly why Alexa is useless using metrics from a Statistical Analysis perspective. It is an easy read and complete read.